# unity 2d tile with vector graphics image doesn't change color when painting tilemap

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, vector-graphics

I am using vector graphics for my game. The problem is after importing the vector file of a simple white square, I created a tile using it and I changed its color to ( let's say ) red. I created a 2dtilemap by right clicking in the object hierarchy. Then I opened my tile palette windows, I drag and drop my square tile ( with changed color ) in the tile palette window. Instead of showing a red square tile, its showing me the (original ) white color tile. Even when i paint, its painting a white square tile instead of red. I don't know why this is happening .... plz help [image]

Answer (score 0):

Whene you drag Sprite, tile pallet get only Texture from this Sprite. Color its property of Sprite.

Comment: but when I did this with a simple png sprite it worked ( with the color tile ) but not in the case of vector sprite. Does that mean vector sprite dont support this ?